# C++ non null terminated char array outputting

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I was trying to output a not null terminated char array to a file.

Actual thing is, I am receiving packets and then printing their fields.

Now as these fields are not null terminated, for example, a data segment which has size of 512 but may or may not be completely occupied.

When I write this data to a file I am using simple << overloaded function which does not know any thing about actual data and only looks for termination of data segment.

So, how can I tell the output function to write only this much **specific number of bytes**?

Instead of using something like this which is expensive to call each time:

```
enter code here  

bytescopied = strncpy(dest, src, maxbytes);

if (bytescopied < 0) { // indicates no bytes copied, parameter error

    throw(fit);          // error handler stuff here

 } else if (bytescopied == maxbytes) {

    dest[maxbytes-1] = '\0';   // force null terminator

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to put exactly `maxbytes` bytes, use `write` method

```
stream.write(buffer, maxbytes);
```

If you can have less bytes in buffer, how do you know how many of them your buffer contains? If `'\0'` marks buffer end, you can write:

```
stream.write(buffer, std::find(buffer, buffer+maxbytes, '\0') - buffer);
```

Comment: In your second call, the entire second parameter is just a roundabout way of calling plain old `strlen`. But in that case, you may as well just use the more idiomatic way for the entire statement: `stream << buffer`.

Comment: No. strlen won't stop after maxbytes.

Comment: `strnlen` will. A strnlen call will look much cleaner: `strnlen(buffer, maxbytes)`. No mucking about with pointers or anything

Comment: `strnlen` has one downside - it's not in standard.

Answer (score 3):

A cheap solution would be to have a buffer that has space for an extra null character and just put a null character at the point when you know the actual size and then output the null-terminated buffer as you already do. Fast and reliable.

Comment: Yep, you can save that extra character into a temporary variable. Once the printing is done, just restore it.

Answer (score 3):

This works, but isn't safe against accidentally calling the standard `char*` version of `operator<<`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned N>
std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& out, const char ( & data ) [N] )
{
    out.write ( data, N ); 
    // or out.write ( data, strnlen ( data, N ) ); 
    // if you want to stop at a '\0' in the data
    return out;
}


struct Foo {
    char   one[5];
    char   two[1];
    char   three[5];
};

int main ( void )
{
    using namespace std;

    Foo foo = {
        { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }, 
        { ' ' }, 
        {'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'} };

    cout << foo.one;
    cout << foo.two;
    cout << foo.three;
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is safer, using a `maxw` type which limits the length of the next `char*` output:

```
struct maxw {
    unsigned n;
    maxw ( unsigned n ) : n ( n ) { }
};

struct maxw_stream {
    std::ostream& stream;
    unsigned n;
    maxw_stream ( std::ostream& stream, unsigned n ) :
            stream ( stream ),
            n ( n ) {
    }
};

maxw_stream operator<< ( std::ostream& out, const maxw& m )
{
    return maxw_stream ( out, m.n );
}

std::ostream& operator<< ( const maxw_stream& out, const char* data )
{
    out.stream.write ( data, strnlen ( data, out.n ) );
    return out.stream;
}

// eg:
cout << maxw(4) << "Hello World!"  << endl;
// Hell\n
cout << maxw(100) << "Hello World!" << endl;
// Hello World!\n
```

Comment: The problem with strnlen is that AFAIK it's not standard. And your template function is nice, but if a buffer is passed as a plain pointer, not an array,  there will be no warning, just standard c-string output function will be called.

Comment: It's been in C99 for ten years, and IIRC C++0x will bring in all C99 standards.

Comment: Well, I searched http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf and couldn't find strnlen.

Answer (score 0):

I see mainly two solutions.

In case of ASCII data:

```
memset(dest,0,destlength); 
bytescopied = strncpy(dest, src, maxbytes);
```

then You'll always have clear null-terminated string in buffor.

Second in case of ASCII data:

```
std::string yourASCII(src,maxbytes);
yourASCII.c_str() // would be null terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the last byte, you can just

```
buffer[buffersize-1] = 0;
```

and then feed buffer to whatever string function you want. If it is shorter, everything will run to the null terminator *that already exists*, and if there was no terminator it will run to the one you just created.

And it's fast :)