# How do I get \0 off my string from C++ when read in C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, unmanaged, microsoft-commerce-server

I'm kind of stuck here.  I'm developing a custom Pipleline component for Commerce Server 2009, but that has little to do with my problem.

In the setup of the pipe, I give the user a windows form to enter some values for configuration.  One of those values is a URL for a SharePoint site.  Commerce Server uses C++ components behind all this pipeline stuff, so the entered values are put into an IDictionary and eventually persisted to the DB via the C++ component from Microsoft.

When I read the string in during pipeline execution, it is handed to me in an IDictionary object from C++.  My C# code sees that URL suffixed with \0\0.  I'm not sure where those are coming from, but my code blows up because it's not a valid URI.  I am trimming the string before I save it and trimming it when I read it and still can't get rid of those.

Any ideas what is causing this and how I can get rid of it?  I prefer not to have a hack like substring it, but something that gets at the root cause.

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: The \0s come from a convention that strings in C/C++ are terminated with \0 (aka null). They're called "null-terminated strings"

Comment: Does your c# code define the Marshaling? You are getting an IDictionary so the string in question is being cast from an Object? It may be possible to Marshal or otherwise convert the Object to a proper String. Can you post some of the code in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this help:

```
string sFixedUrl = "hello\0\0".Trim('\0');
```

Comment: I think that will solve it, but it is a hack just like Substring. It does not address the cause of the problem.

Comment: I think the root cause must something outside of my control on the MS side of the equation as ltcmelo suggests.  I'll go with the Trim solution, hack or not, because it works and I'm reading all strings in through a "NullSafeString" object I wrote, so this is good enough and works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

As the others' posts explained, strings in C are null-terminated. (Notice that C++, however, already provides a string type which doesn't depend on that.)

Your case is just a bit different because you're getting double-null-terminated string. I'm not an expert here, so anyone should feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. But this looks like a typical string representation for unicode/i18n aware applications in Windows which use wide characters. Please, take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx).

One guess is that the application which is persisting the string into the database is not using a "portable" strategy. For example, it might be persisting the string buffer considering its size in **raw bytes** instead of its actual **length**. The former would be counting the extra two zeros in the end (and, consequently, persisting them too) while the latter would discard them.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?NonNullTerminatedString) site:

A string in C is simply an array of characters, with the final character set to the NUL character (ascii/unicode point 0). This null-terminator is required; a string is ill-formed if it isn't there. The string literal token in C/C++ ("string") guarantees this.

```
 const char *str = "foo";
```

is the same as

```
 const char *str = {'f', 'o', 'o', 0};
```

So as soon as the C++ component gets your IDictionary, it will add the null-terminated string to the end.  If you want to remove it, you will have to remove the null terminated char from the end before sending back the dictionary.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542339/c-non-null-terminated-char-array-outputting) post on how to remove a null terminated character.  Basically you need to know the exact size and trim it off.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique you can use is an array of characters and the length of the array.  An array of characters does not need a terminating null character.

When you pass this data structure, you must pass the length also.  The convention for the C-style strings is to determine the end of the string by searching for a '\0' (or in Unicode, '\0\0').  Since the array doesn't have the terminating characters, the length is always needed.

A much better solution is to use the `std::string`.  It doesn't append null characters.  When you need compatibility, or the C-style format, use the `c_str()` method.  I have to use this technique with my program because the GUI framework has its own string data type that is incompatible with `std::string`.